# What does de stand for in crx/de?

Tags: aem, crx

From JSR-283 - CRX stands for Content Repository [Extreme](http://crxinaction.blogspot.in/2012/07/what-is-crx.html). What does 'de' stand for? (German?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Though this question doesn't meet Stackoverflow standards, for the sake of others having the same doubt I am answering this.

CRXDE is **Content Repository Extreme Development Environment** and it is visible within the CRXDE console itself.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Content Repository Extreme/Development Environment**